# How to threshold an image 32 bit using Otsu’s Binarization?

Tags: opencv, python-3.x

I tried all the possibilities using the following instruction:

```
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

But it always gives me the same error:

> error: (-215) src.type() == CV_8UC1 in function cv::threshold

There is a possibility to threshold an image 32-bit, single channel ??! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to OpenCV doc for [cv::threshold](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#cv2.threshold):

> Currently, the Otsu’s method is implemented only for 8-bit (`CV_8UC1`) images.

For other methods, according to the documentation, are valid single-channel matrices, 8-bit (`CV_8UC1`) or 32-bit floating point (`CV_32FC1`).

However, it should work also for 16-bit (`CV_16SC1`) matrices

For `cv::adaptiveThreshold`, type must be `CV_8UC1`.

Comment: @ Miki. Then it's impossible. Is it valid for the other thresholding methods too?

Comment: It doesn't function for Adaptive Thresholding too; I'm interest in Otsu's method, it's not problem. Thanks for the info @Miki

Comment: @ Miki, now it is ok. Thanks for the useful answer ;)